# can we write function name same as class name in c++?

Tags: c++

As in java we can have same method name as of class name , but can we do same in c++?

```
class Test
{
     void Test() //it is not a constructor and it is a method
     {}
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with java. You just used it as an example. The issue is in c++... please update your tags accordingly.

Comment: If this is something you genuinely want to do, then in all likelihood you've not named things very well.

Comment: I mean, you could have tested it and see it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

```
// foo.cc
class Test {
    public:
        void Test();
};
```

No:

```
$ g++ foo.cc 
foo.cc:3:19: error: return type specification for constructor invalid
         void Test();
               ^
```

C++ assumes methods named after the class are constructors.